# Visual Studio code coverage for a referenced library

Tags: c#, .net

[image]In my solution there is library (Project) that I have built.

Then there is the project for unit testing.

When I run the code coverage, it only displays the Unit test libraries coverage. But I want to run the unit tests against the library and see the coverage of the library.

How can I do that?

Please see attached

Comment: Are you saying that you only get coverage reported for the tests themselves and not for what those tests are calling into? -- You do have the library project in the solutions file, right, and are referring to it? (as opposed to just referencing an assembly).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I have the project in the same solution. However, UnitTest Project only generating a coverage report for itself, which is useless for me.

Comment: That is very odd.

Comment: I have added screen capture.